# MQTT with TLS for TI CC3200 fails with 'Bad CA file' error

Tags: mqtt, aws-iot, tls, ti-cc3200

This topic seems to pop up everywhere but, without a conclusion as to how to get MQTT-TLS for CC3200 running. So, here goes one more.

## Goal

Connect TI CC3200 board to AWS IoT broker via TLS.

## Steps

### Get certificates

To get the keys and certificates for TLS with AWS IoT, I used AWS CLI as shown here:

```
aws iot create-keys-and-certificate --set-as-active --certificate-pem-outfile cert.crt --private-key-outfile private.key --public-key-outfile public.key --region us-east-1
```

The root CA is downloaded as so:

```
wget https://www.symantec.com/content/en/us/enterprise/verisign/roots/VeriSign-Class%203-Public-Primary-Certification-Authority-G5.pem -O rootCA.pem
```

### Change format

Based on the [TI wiki](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/CC3200_SSL_Demo_Application#Files.2FVariables_related_to_TLS.2FSSL), the board requires these files to be in DER format. Therefore, I used `openssl` on an AWS EC2 instance to convert the certificates as shown below. This [link](http://info.ssl.com/article.aspx?id=12149) was helpful to arrive at the commands.

```
openssl rsa -inform pem -in private.key -outform der -out private.der
openssl x509 -in cert.crt -outform der -out cert.der
openssl x509 -in rootCA.pem -outform der -out rootCA.der
```

### Flash the certificates

The `.der` files need to renamed as `<someId>.der` where `<someId>` will be provided as input to a structure. See [here](https://e2e.ti.com/support/wireless_connectivity/simplelink_wifi_cc31xx_cc32xx/f/968/p/373074/1313727#1313727) for the discussion. Thus, the following renaming was done:

- `private.der` to `126.der`
- `cert.der` to `127.der`
- `rootCA.der` to `128.der`

All of the `.der` files were flashed at `/cert/` location on the board.

### MQTT TLS

In the Paho Embedded-C project, [source code](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.embedded-c/blob/master/MQTTClient-C/src/cc3200/MQTTCC3200.c) is available for the TI CC3200 module. This module will be used to make a TLS connection with this method `int TLSConnectNetwork(Network *n, char* addr, int port, SlSockSecureFiles_t* certificates, unsigned char sec_method, unsigned int cipher, char server_verify)` where, `SlSockSecureFiles_t` is the argument of interest for TLS. This argument is defined in `socket.h` from TI as an array of `_u8`. (I could see this locally in the zipped file of documentation.)

```
typedef struct sock_secureFiles
 {
     _u8                     secureFiles[4];
 } SlSockSecureFiles_t;
```

The array is created as shown below.

```
SlSockSecureFiles_t secure_file;
secure_file.secureFiles[0] = 126;
secure_file.secureFiles[1] = 127;
secure_file.secureFiles[2] = 128;
secure_file.secureFiles[3] = 0;
```

The numbers are the ID of the files under `/cert` folder.

Other arguments for `TLSNetworkConnect()` are set as follows:

- `SL_SO_SEC_METHOD_TLSV1_2` for security method for TLS v1.2.
- `SL_SEC_MASK_TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA` for cipher suite.
- `0` for `server_verify`

## Results

The TLS connection does not happen.

### Error

The connection to broker keeps failing with error code for `Bad CA file`.

### SSL session

I tried an `openssl` session with the `.der` files and connection seems to go through fine.

```
openssl s_client -connect xxxx.iot.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:8883 -CAfile rootCA.pem -key private.der -keyform der -cert cert.der -certform DER
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=2 C = US, O = "VeriSign, Inc.", OU = VeriSign Trust Network, OU = "(c) 2006 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only", CN = VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5
verify return:1
depth=1 C = US, O = Symantec Corporation, OU = Symantec Trust Network, CN = Symantec Class 3 Secure Server CA - G4
verify return:1
depth=0 C = US, ST = Washington, L = Seattle, O = "Amazon.com, Inc.", CN = *.iot.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
verify return:1
140493918627480:error:14094412:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert bad certificate:s3_pkt.c:1487:SSL alert number 42
140493918627480:error:140790E5:SSL routines:ssl23_write:ssl handshake failure:s23_lib.c:177:
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=US/ST=Washington/L=Seattle/O=Amazon.com, Inc./CN=*.iot.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
   i:/C=US/O=Symantec Corporation/OU=Symantec Trust Network/CN=Symantec Class 3 Secure Server CA - G4
 1 s:/C=US/O=Symantec Corporation/OU=Symantec Trust Network/CN=Symantec Class 3 Secure Server CA - G4
   i:/C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=VeriSign Trust Network/OU=(c) 2006 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only/CN=VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIGGjCCBQKgAwIBAgIQLnQIWjfERfw1k/3WWKINNTANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADB+
.......
05vnq6DeWRLXoQYZoJm9ysbfVsRx9QB3YRy0C79Cie5bvmO7ib2sQ0OdfB42eg+v
I9KM/MH7QgMiCeHVBnoxdysrLBF9cyGt3MJHwzVi
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/C=US/ST=Washington/L=Seattle/O=Amazon.com, Inc./CN=*.iot.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
issuer=/C=US/O=Symantec Corporation/OU=Symantec Trust Network/CN=Symantec Class 3 Secure Server CA - G4
---
No client certificate CA names sent
Client Certificate Types: RSA sign, DSA sign, ECDSA sign
Requested Signature Algorithms: ECDSA+SHA512:RSA+SHA512:ECDSA+SHA384:RSA+SHA384:ECDSA+SHA256:RSA+SHA256:DSA+SHA256:ECDSA+SHA224:RSA+SHA224:DSA+SHA224:ECDSA+SHA1:RSA+SHA1:DSA+SHA1
Shared Requested Signature Algorithms: ECDSA+SHA512:RSA+SHA512:ECDSA+SHA384:RSA+SHA384:ECDSA+SHA256:RSA+SHA256:DSA+SHA256:ECDSA+SHA224:RSA+SHA224:DSA+SHA224:ECDSA+SHA1:RSA+SHA1:DSA+SHA1
Peer signing digest: SHA512
Server Temp Key: ECDH, P-256, 256 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 3387 bytes and written 138 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
    Session-ID: 5B23B08B6883D21....62AD324D2DD
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: F5EBEA2F775C5E6....A79E48373756C75207B0D
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1529065611
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

Comment: TI is providing some response [here](https://e2e.ti.com/support/wireless_connectivity/simplelink_wifi_cc31xx_cc32xx/f/968/p/700012/2581381#2581381).